# Error en el uso del comando COPY

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

Buenas noches Comunidad:

Intento ejecutar la siguiente sentencia en PostgreSQL:

```
COPY ad_alert (ad_alert_id, ad_client_id, ad_org_id, isactive) FROM stdin;
               100       0            0      N
```

Y me arroja un error at or near 100.

¿Hay algo mal en mi sentencia `copy`?

gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Que programa cliente estás usando para ejecutar la sentencia en PostgreSQL?

Comment: PgAdmin de Postgrsql 9.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PgAdmin` no es capaz de ejecutar `copy ... from stdin`. Te sugiero 2 alternativas:

1. Si deseas usar `PgAdmin`, te sugiero de copiar los datos que quieres a un archivo (digamos `c:\test.dat` por ejemplo) y ejecutar la sentencia siguiente:

   ```
   COPY ad_alert (ad_alert_id, ad_client_id, ad_org_id, isactive) FROM 'c:\test.dat';
   ```
2. Usa `psql` en vez de `PgAdmin`. Usando `psql` puedes ejecutar la sentencia siguiente:

   ```
   db=# copy ad_alert(ad_alert_id, ad_client_id, ad_org_id, isactive) from stdin;
   Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
   End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
   >> 100  0       0       N
   >> \.
   COPY 1
   ```

**Nota adicional**

Si decides usar la primera opción copiando los datos a un archivo, cuidado con el formato del archivo. En particular, evita salvaguardarlo en UTF-8 **con BOM**. Yo cometí este error, y no me funcionó correctamente porque el archivo contenía el carácter BOM al comienzo (`U+FEFF`). Y creo recordar de una pregunta pasada tuya que ya has tenido problemas con ese carácter en uno de tus archivos. Por eso lo menciono por si acaso.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta. Te comento que la instrucción que puse proviene de un archivo .sql el cual contiene mas de 1000 líneas de instructiones y se especifican cientos de veces el comando COPY. Lo que hice fue abrir el PSQL CONSOLE, escribí la línea de comando openxp=# -d openxp -f openxp_schema.sql >> dump_error.log  al dar enter me lleva al prompt openxp=# sin mostrar mensaje. Lo que intento con la línea de comando es que se ejecute el archivo .sql donde tengo las muchas instrucciones para la creación de la estructura de la BD.

Comment: funcionó con la siguiente instrucción psql -U openxp -d openxp -f openxp_schema.sql >> dump_error.log